# Azure ADB2C custom policy returns: "The metadata returned by endpoint ... is invalid."

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to set up an invitation link to our Azure B2C. I have to the best of my ability used the guidance provided [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite) and [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-a-jwt-to-invoke-an-azure-ad-b2c-flow-using-id-token-hint-13752ee6d9df). When clicking the link generated, I am presented with the following error:

["AADB2C: The metadata returned by endpoint 'https://{my site}.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration' is invalid."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loHnK.png)

Using the trace on Application Insights, I can understand the following:

```
{
  "Kind": "FatalException",
  "Content": {
    "Time": "3:39 AM",
    "Exception": {
      "Kind": "Handled",
      "HResult": "80131500",
      "Message": "The metadata returned by endpoint 'https://{my website}.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration' is invalid.",
      "Data": {
        "IsPolicySpecificError": false,
        "metadataUri": "https://{my website}.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        "cachedItemIdentifier": "HTTPS://{my website}.AZUREWEBSITES.NET/.WELL-KNOWN/OPENID-CONFIGURATION"
      },
      "Exception": {
        "Kind": "Handled",
        "HResult": "80131500",
        "Message": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.",
        "Data": {

        }​
      }
    }​
  }
}
```

So there is clearly something wrong with the URL that is being generated. However, I am just unable to figure out what with where my skill set is at. I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#code-try-0) to make sure my SSL certificate is properly set up, and I believe I have that correct. Any help will go a long way.

Comment: To point you in the right direction we need to see the metadata url to analyse it.